# How to unify @GenericGenerator declaration for multiple entities using same custom id generator?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, id-generation

There are many entities in my project that utilize the same custom `IdentifierGenerator` for `@Id` generation using `SpringDataJPA/Hibernate`.

An example entity;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHAIRS")
public class ChairEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "myGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(strategy = "a.b.jpa.generator.MyGenerator", name = "myGenerator")
    protected String id;

    // rest of the entity
}
```

But I do not want to repeat `@GenericGenerator` decleration for every id field of every entity. Is there no way to hide this annotation that contains an ugly hardcoded full class name inside?

***post scriptum*** 
I was previously utilizing `@MappedSuperClass` with a `BaseEntity` class containing `id` field, but due to some technical reasons I had to abandon utilizing such a superclass. Obviously that is the easiest solution to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution I came up with was a Java trick, all my entities are under `a.b.jpa.entity`, and my generator in `a.b.jpa.generator`, and since `@GenericGenerator` can be used on class directly, I created a `package-info.java` for `a.b.jpa.entity` package with the following contents;

```
@GenericGenerator(strategy = "a.b.jpa.generator.MyGenerator", name = MyGenerator.generatorName)
package a.b.jpa.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import a.b.jpa.generator.MyGenerator;
```

That annotates all classes under `a.b.jpa.entity` with the `@GenericGenerator`, which is perfect solution for my question. Essentially making it available for all entities.

code of the generator;

```
public class MyGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    public static final String generatorName = "myGenerator";

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return GeneratorUtil.generate();
    }
}
```

and the entities in the following state;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHAIRS")
public class ChairEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = MyGenerator.generatorName)
    protected String id;

    // rest of the entity
}
```

Which did the trick, now the `@GenericGenerator` is defined in a single location, supplying the `MyGenerator` details to all my entities, if any of them wishes to use it, they just utilize `@GeneratedValue`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [@MappedSuperclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "myGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(strategy = "a.b.jpa.generator.MyGenerator", name = "myGenerator")
    protected String id;

    // getters, setters here

}
```

Then, your Entities can extend it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHAIRS")
public class ChairEntity extends BaseEntity { ... }
```

Comment: I was utilizing this previously, and it is correct that this is a better solution, but my requirements were forcing me not to use such a superclass. I modified the question, but your answer is proper for this question in a broader scope.